# Index out of range when trying to read an array of parsed JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have a function that reads the JSON from the NYTimes API - I'm trying to populate a table view with the headlines. This is the function:

```
func getJSON() {
    let url = NSURL(string: nyTimesURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        let json = JSON(data: data!)
        let results = json["results"].arrayValue

        for title in results {

            let titles = title["title"].stringValue
            print(titles)

            let count: Int = title.count
            self.numberOfStories = count

            self.headlines.append(titles)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("\n\n\nHeadlines array: \(self.headlines)\n\n\n")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And then as class variables I have

```
var headlines = [String]()
var numberOfStories = 1
```

If I hardcode the cell.textLabel, I can run the app and see the `headlines` array is properly populated with all the headlines. But if I try to set the cell label to `self.headlines[indexPath.row]`, I get an index out of range crash. I've tried putting the `tableView.reloadData()` call in the main thread (`DispatchQueue.main.async{}`) but that's not the issue.

How can I get the headlines to properly display?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Tableview methods:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.numberOfStories
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JSONcell", for: indexPath) as! JSONTableViewCell

    cell.cellLabel.text = self.headlines[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

Comment: None of the code you posted makes any attempt to access an array. Where do you actually call `self.headlines[indexPath.row]`? When and where do you call `getJSON`?

Comment: And you must use `DispatchQueue.main.async` to call `reloadData` from inside the data task completion block.

Comment: @rmaddy I added my tableview methods - I call `self.headlines[indexPath.row]` in my `cellForRow` method to set the labels.

Comment: And putting the reloadData call inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: All UI updated must be done on the main queue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of your `numberOfStories` property. Use `headlines.count` instead.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return headlines.count
}
```

Your `cellForRowAt` and `numberOfRowsInSection` must be based on the same data.

And be sure you call `reloadData` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` since the data task completion block is being called from a background queue.

Comment: Ok, I see - `numberOfStories` was kind of redundant. I made the changes and it works now, thanks! To confirm, `self.tableView.reloadData()` is in the proper place here (in the for loop)? I added the `DispatchQueue.main.async` around it, I just want to make sure it's on that it's inside the loop.

Comment: Actually the call to `reloadData` must be after the for loop. It's pointless to reload the whole table for each added item. Reload it once after adding all of the items.